is it possible to make pnpm handle the git-hosted package
When I using pnpm 9 to install the git-hosted package in github actions, shows error:
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm warn deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
Progress: resolved 1904, reused 0, downloaded 1800, added 1792
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: > @codemirror/autocomplete@6.12.0 prepare
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: > cm-buildhelper src/index.ts
Progress: resolved 1904, reused 0, downloaded 1902, added 1903
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm notice
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.7.0 -> 10.8.2
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.2
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm notice
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm error code 1
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm error path /home/runner/setup-pnpm/node_modules/.bin/store/v3/tmp/_tmp_2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm error command failed
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm error command sh -c cm-buildhelper src/index.ts
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-08-10T08_44_50_487Z-debug-0.log
...2028_bdafe4b9f3a3a25bf8a949127ee2568c npm-install: Failed
 ERR_PNPM_PREPARE_PACKAGE  Failed to prepare git-hosted package fetched from "https://codeload.github.com/overleaf/codemirror-autocomplete/tar.gz/2aff95fc5d6cda311537ed62066c9a0afbbbcad8": @codemirror/autocomplete@6.12.0 npm-install: `npm install`

this is the git hosted package defined in package.json like:
"@codemirror/autocomplete": "github:overleaf/codemirror-autocomplete#main-overleaf",

and this is the pnpm github actions step look like:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v3
        with:
          version: 9
      - name: Build React App
        run: |
          pnpm install
          pnpm run build
        env:
          CI: false

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? PS: I have tried the official talk https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/6005

did you solve it?

no, I did not solve it. and switch to npm works fine.

I was able to solve it by publishing my package to npm and installed as a normal package.
